# Winforms load slowly when using SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce, mdi

I have a problem with my Winforms program taking a long time (about 15 sec) to start after I switched from storing its settings in a text file to SQL Server CE database. I've moved all the heavy load operation in a background worker, and left a few basic stuffs in the shown event but the GUI takes quite a while to show up.

I have a class library to handle all the database operations (create, insert, select, delete, update). When this class is instantiated, it checks for the database's existence, then creates the database if doesn't exist, else it will test the connection string and leave it there until any operation is called. This happens every time I open a form. So is it bad to create a new object of this class in every form or should I share the object between the forms? (The connection is closed after each operation)

Secondly, I have a MDI form with many children forms, and they appear depending on what button user clicks and dispose the unused ones. The MDI parent and children flicker when they open. Should I just hide the unused ones instead of disposing them? I tried double buffering the children but it didn't help much.

Comment: Maybe this? http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/faq-why-is-opening-my-sql-server.html

Comment: @ErikEJ all 3 scenarios don't apply to my case

Comment: Opening a database connection on first access to your lib and leaving it open and unused could help...

Comment: @ErikEJ I also have a splash screen, should I instantiate database object here before calling the MDI parent form?